# Quicksort using middle element not giving correct answer

Tags: python, quicksort

I am implementing quicksort using middle as pivot element. Here is my implementation;

```
def partition1(arr,low,high): 

   pivot = (low+high)//2    # pivot 
#print (low,high)

   while low<=high: 
    #print (low,high)

    # If current element is smaller than the pivot 
    while arr[low]<arr[pivot]: 
        low+=1
        #print (low,high)
        if low>high:
            return low
            #break
    while arr[high]>arr[pivot]:
        high-=1
    arr[low],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[low] 
    low+=1
    high-=1
return low



def quick_Sort(arr,low,high): 
    if low < high: 
    #print(arr)

    # pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
    # at right place 
    pi = partition1(arr,low,high)
    print(pi)

    # Separately sort elements before 
    # partition and after partition 
    quick_Sort(arr, low, pi-1) 
    quick_Sort(arr, pi+1, high)
```

Here is the example case I am testing it on;

```
quick_Sort([-1,6,4,2,3,1],0,5)
```

But my code is providing following output;

```
[-1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6]
[-1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6]
[-1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

It seems to be getting stuck.Can I please get some advice on fixing it?thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use a debugger, where does it *seem* to get stuck?

Comment: actually, I haven't used debugger yet.By stuck I mean, same answer each time is appearing.Is there a way to find the wrong/incorrect step?help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: quick_Sort(arr, low, pi-1) 
quick_Sort(arr, pi+1, high) - these does not include the pi element, but the one before, and the one after.

Comment: I dont quite remember the quicksort, but I guess that the last call to quick_Sort should be called with pi instead of pi+1

Comment: @Stefan using pi in the last step works.can you kindly explain, what changed here?I really want to understand it.thanks

Comment: @jayant - the code is using a variation of Hoare partition scheme, where the pivot and elements == pivot can end up anywhere, so the returned index may or may not be an index to the pivot, so the returned index can not be excluded from the recursive calls.